# How would I reconstruct the floor from a still shot?

Tags: tracking

I have a still shot, I'm trying to reconstruct the FOV and orientation with the reconstruction tools, and since I have a square plane in the middle of the scene I thought that would be easy, but I can't figure out how to get any of the tools to work. It keeps saying "Three tracks *with bundles* are required" but I have no idea what a bundle is and I can't find anything explaining them.

I know I've seen it done before, I just don't remember where

Comment: You can use the [BLAM add-on](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam) to do this.